# U-Boot: controlling SDRAM refresh rate

Tags: memory, refresh, u-boot

My goal is to find the pice of code in denx u-boot, which controls (sets) the refresh rate for the external memory (sdram/ddr memory).

In particular, I have a [Tiny4412](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/tiny4412) evaluation board, which features an Samsung exynos processor. At the moment I am digging through the u-boot code base to find the code, which initializes the external memory and sets the refresh rate.

Do you know the code, which is in charge of this task and the file that implements it?

Furhtermore, I was curious, whether it is possible to set the refresh rate after the boot process finished (e.g. using a kernel module)?

Answer (score 0):

Your board is not in mainline u-boot. The Exynos4412 chip is only supported in the Odroid board, and not the board you are using.

It is NOT good practice to modify the refresh rate after the bootloader has set it.

Comment: I know that it might not be a good idea. However, this is for experimental purposes only.